# How to design HTML table using row span or column span

Tags: html

I am trying to create HTML table structure like following using Column span or row span. But I can't get exactly what I want. Any one can help to get the following table structure?

```
--------------------
|c |   row1     | c|
|o  ------------  o|
|l |            | l|
|u |     row2   | u|
|m |            | m|
|n |            | n|
--------------------
```

Could any one can help me to get this structure in HTMl Table?

Comment: try to add some sample data with table grid structure.

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>
            C<br>o<br>l<br>u<br>m<br>n
        </td>
        <td>
            row1
        </td>
        <td rowspan=2>
            C<br>o<br>l<br>u<br>m<br>n
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```